# Do I need async-supported for jetty QoS filter to work

Tags: jetty, servlet-3.0

Do I really need `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` also in my web.xml file for jetty QoS filter to work? Does jetty QoS filter work with servlet 2.5? Or the servlet has to be 3.0+?